# I want to template an object property, by type, within another datatemplate

Tags: wpf

I have a view model for a DataGrid that is like this:

```
public class Cell
{
    public CellValue CellValue { get; }
}
```

And the CellValue property can be of several types:

```
public class CellValue
{
    public double Value { get; }
}

public class TwoValueCell : CellValue
{
    public double Value2 { get; }
}
```

The DataGrid is binding the ItemsSource to a list of my rows and cells.

The DataGrid binds the data as expected: I get a Cell in each DataGridCell. So I have a style in the resources like this (local resources for now):

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentHost"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Cell}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CellValue}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

I like having the template bound to the view model type ...

The question is: instead of the Binding on the TextBlock, I want to inflate another DataTemplate there which I can somehow define again by specific CellValue Types.

In other words, in psudocode it might look like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Cell}">
    <Grid>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CellValue}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

But I would need to define the specific CellValue data templates somewhere ...

The bottom line is in having one Type for the DataGridCell --- and having a data template for that type --- but then having several specific types on the property of the cell, and I want to define custom data templates based on the actual type of the PROPERTY.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ContentControl.

```
<DataTemplate ...>
    <Grid>
       <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty}">
         <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
           <DataTemplate ...>  ...  </DataTemplate>
         </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
       </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: YES! I just now tried that and it is working! It is working with custom types on the nested data template as well ...